# BitmapDrawable created from InputStream has wrong Target Density

Tags: android, image, android-layout

I need to create some BitmapDrawables using an InputStream.  I'm getting the InputStreams from a Uri. But, resource drawables are drawn with the wrong target density.

The device I'm using should have a target density of 320.  Instead the BitmapDrawable is being created with a target density of 160 (bad, image displays half-sized)

In following example, the target density is wrong - sets it to 160:

```
Uri fromResource = new Uri.Builder()
  .scheme(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE)
  .authority("com.myapp.whatever")
  .path(String.valueOf(R.drawable.default_image))
  .build();

InputStream resourceStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(fromResource);
// correct image, wrong size
Drawable resourceDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), resourceStream);
```

If I use the other way, it sets the target density correctly - sets to 320:

```
// same image, but right size
Drawable thisWayWorks = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.default_image);
```

**Why is the target density wrong in the first example?**  Shouldn't the BitmapDrawable correctly set the density using the Resources obj that gets passed in?

"default_image" has md, hd, and xd assets. I tried testing removing the md and hd assets so that I knew only the xd image was being loaded, but had the same results.

More info, why I want to do this:

I (should) have an image on disk, and another default image as a drawable resource (to display if image on disk can't be found). My whole pipeline gets simplified if I can always load images using a Uri, and not have a special case for "this Uri actually points to a resource, not disk, content, asset, etc"

Comment: To make it even worse, I have the same problem but I get the wrong target locale with the first methode for some reason!